# Display table view section title

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have three strings and each one either says True or False. Depending on which strings say True I would display them in the table view. Here is the code I have:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  if ([appDelegate.showFirstField isEqualToString:@"True"]) {
    if (indexPath.section==2) {
        cell.textLabel.text=@"First Field Title";
    }
  }

  if ([appDelegate.showSecondField isEqualToString:@"True"]) {
    if (indexPath.section==3) {
        cell.textLabel.text=@"Second Field Title";
    }
  }

  if ([appDelegate.showThirdField isEqualToString:@"True"]) {
    if (indexPath.section==4) {
        cell.textLabel.text=@"Third Field Title";
    }
  }
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
   //#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
   // Return the number of sections.
   int sectionNum = 2;
   if ([appDelegate.showFirstField isEqualToString:@"True"]) {
     sectionNum += 1;
   }
   if ([appDelegate.showSecondField isEqualToString:@"True"]) {
     sectionNum += 1;
   }
   if ([appDelegate.showThirdField isEqualToString:@"True"]) {
     sectionNum += 1;
   }
   return sectionNum;
}
```

The issue is that if `showFirstField` and `showThirdField` are True and `showSecondField` is False then the section title wont be set correctly. Is there a way I can set the title to the next available section.

Comment: In the first method the variable cell doesn't appear to have been defined, unless it is an ivar, which would be odd. The usual practice is to define an identifier, attempt to dequeue a cell with that id, and if that fails instantiate a new one. For the rest, it's really not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Did you want the same number of sections as true fields or the same number of rows? Also confused as to why the App Delegate ivars are `NSString` and not `bool`. cellForRowAtIndexPath creates cells- it doesn't set section titles. If you used it you'd just end up setting the textlabel of every row in that section to the same string

Comment: @RichTolley My table view is grouped. I have a guaranteed 2 rows. The next 3 rows are dependent on the true or false values. The reason I have them as strings is because I get them from a webservice and they are strings there. If anyone of them is true I want to show the text in the next available table row there is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple hours working on it I took it from a different approach and this code works for me. **set the `check` booleans to false and as global variables**

```
if ([appDelegate.showFirstField isEqualToString:@"True"] && checkFirst == FALSE){
    if (indexPath.section >1 && indexPath.section==indexPath.section) {
        checkFirst = TRUE;
        cell.textLabel.text=@"First Field Title";                
    }
}
else if ([appDelegate.showSecondField isEqualToString:@"True"] && checkSecond == FALSE){
    if (indexPath.section >1 && indexPath.section==indexPath.section) {
        checkSecond = TRUE;
        cell.textLabel.text=@"Second Field Title";
    }
}
else if ([appDelegate.showThirdField isEqualToString:@"True"] && checkThird == FALSE){
    if (indexPath.section >1 && indexPath.section==indexPath.section) {
        checkThirdField = TRUE;
        cell.textLabel.text=@"Third Field Title";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code if `showFirstField` and `showThirdField` are True and `showSecondField` is False then `sectionNum` will be **4**. Hence the possible values for `indexPath.section` will be **0,1,2 & 3**.
In this code

```
if ([appDelegate.showThirdField isEqualToString:@"True"]) {
    if (indexPath.section==4) {
        cell.textLabel.text=@"Third Field Title";
    }
  }
```

Even though this condition `[appDelegate.showThirdField isEqualToString:@"True"]` is true, the other condition `indexPath.section==4` will be false.

So change your

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
   //#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
   // Return the number of sections.
   int sectionNum = 2;
   if ([appDelegate.showFirstField isEqualToString:@"True"]) {
     sectionNum += 1;
   }
   if ([appDelegate.showSecondField isEqualToString:@"True"]) {
     sectionNum += 1;
   }
   if ([appDelegate.showThirdField isEqualToString:@"True"]) {
     sectionNum += 1;
   }
   return sectionNum;
}
```

to

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{  
   return 5;
}
```

Comment: If I have my section number at 5 then if I have none of them as True then I should only see 2 sections. Depending on if they are true or false I want them to show.